# How to fix infinite loop using Set in React?

Tags: typescript

I implemented a function in `ReactJs` to generate unique numbers given the array from where the function should choose and the number of generated random numbers.

Here is the function

```
 static randomUniqueNumbers(numbers: number[], count: number) {
    let nums = new Set<number>();
    let number = 0;

    while ((nums.size < count)) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
        nums.add(numerator);
    }
    return nums;
}
```

I am using this to generate 90% of times 3 numbers from a set greaters than 3
So I am calling it like this

```
randomUniqueNumbers([2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10], 3)
```

And it's working fine.

The problem is that in a specific case, I am calling this

```
randomUniqueNumbers([2], 3)
```

because I want the same random number 3 times
And here in this case the app crashes and even the whole browser freeze.

NB: I don't want to test on `count` variable because I don't know if there will be futur changes.

I know that `Set` cannot contain the same number twice but I wonder if there is a better solution than checking the size of the given array to choose from.

Also I would love to know the exact problem.

Please ask for more clarifications if you don't understand something.

Comment: *"...because I want the same random number 3 times."* Then why are you using a `Set`? It cannot have the same element in it more than once. That's its purpose. Also, "the same random number" doesn't match the function's name, which says it produces **unique** random numbers.

Comment: Yes I know that, then are you saying that the only work around is to call the function only when numbers.length >=  count ?

Comment: Provided `numbers` doesn't have any duplicates in it, yes. How could the set's `size` ever be `>= count` if there aren't `count` (or more) **unique** numbers in `numbers`?

Comment: Yes provided `numbers` doesn't have duplicates

Comment: you are not adding the generated number to the set here: `nums.add(numerator)`

Comment: for `randomUniqueNumbers([2], 3)` the generated number is always 0. You start with an empty set. So the set never grows and you get an infinite loop. That is why your browser freezes.

Comment: btw. This has nothing to do with react. This is just JS or TS.

Comment: You should describe better, what exactly you are trying to achieve.
A set with 3 random numbers. A set with count times random numbers?
Just tree numbers? Does it have to be a Set?
Should they even be random, or do you need one random number, three times in a set or array?  Or are you trying to pick count times numbers from the provided array, but randomly?

Comment: @henk Thank you for the clarifications, I am trying to pick randomly 3 different and unique numbers, that's why I used the `Set`. But I have different use cases where I need to generate one random number and use it 3 times

Comment: @Amine sorry but I still don't get it.
`randomUniqueNumbers([2], 3)` should generate 3 unique random numbers? What is the first parameter `[2]` for then?

Comment: @henk I wanted a generic solution so that based on the array I pass as a parameter, if its length is 1, the function return `count` (in this case 3) same number passed in the array, if the length is greater or equal to `count` the function do the current job. My problem is I want to keep the same logic but add error handling logic.

Comment: So are you trying to fix the infinite loop problem, or are you trying to keep the logic and add error handling? For me it is still unclear what is your goal.

Comment: @henk As I mentioned in the last previous comment, I wanted error handling and keep the same logic, but I did fix it with a more specific way (I didn't liked the solution though) and I am not working on that anymore.